# Advice for an experiment

Tags: power, motor, magnetics, mechanical, electro-mechanical

I am thinking to do an experiment which is a piston crank mechanism that works on the magnetic force attraction and repulsion.
I want to place a stationary ferromagnetic bar in a coil of wire near the top of the piston head and excite it with a dc current supply to create a static magnetic field around it.
Then I want to bring another ferromagnetic bar that will play the role of the piston which will repel and attract to the stationary magnet; which will give this piston a continuous reciprocating motion.

I should use a commutator with brushes to switch the poles of the stationary magnet in order to achieve the attraction and repulsion process, and I will connect this commutator within the crankshaft.
Also, To control the speed of the reciprocating piston, I may put an adjustable resistor for the dc supply circuit so that it can change the current magnitude whenever I need to strengthen/weaken the static magnetic field which in turns strengthen/weaken the magnetic force attraction and repulsion which will increase/reduce the piston speed.

Does this experiment seem applicable or practical? If it is, what comments do you have for more improvement or fixing some mistakable thoughts in this experiment?

Comment: The big problem with this is that most of your magnetic circuit is through the air and air has a permeability of 0.001 times that of steel. All sensible magnetic circuits keep air gaps to the minimum (for given manufacturing tolerances and price point) and ferrous path to the maximum. You scheme will be weak and may not be able to turn the crank.

Comment: @Transistor is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: I don't think so. A rotary motor is far simpler, very efficient and with three-phase, for example, gives constant torque throughout its rotation unlike a reciprocating engine which will pulse at various parts of the cycle. (Writing tip: in English there is no space before a punctuation mark and there is one after the mark.)

Comment: Before you go experimenting.  Get two magnets.  Bring them close together and see how much force is exerted and their reaction.  Now, extrapolate that to moving pistons.  Seems to be a scale problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I want to bring another ferromagnetic bar that will play the role
> of the piston which will **repel** and attract to the stationary magnet;
> which will give this piston a continuous reciprocating motion.

That won't work. The 'ferromagnetic bar' will only be attracted to the electromagnet. What you could do is switch off the electromagnet just before the piston gets to TDC (top dead center), then the inertia of the flywheel will (hopefully) keep it turning until the next upstroke, when the commutator turns the electromagnet back on.

A better way might be to put a permanent magnet on the piston, then switch the electromagnet on when the piston gets to TDC. With correct magnet orientation and coil excitation the piston will be attracted to the core when off, and repelled by it when on.

Note that the magnetic force decreases rapidly with distance, so you only get a strong force when the piston is close to the electromagnet. For best results you want a wide piston and short stroke.

Answer (score 1):

Many machines of this sort have been made; they are called "solenoid motors" or "solenoid engines".

As has already been mentioned, they are not very efficient due to the poor magnetic circuit, so they are mainly of interest to model builders who would like to imitate the crankshaft and piston operation of an internal combustion (or steam) engine using purely electrical parts.

But if you want to build one anyway, you can find plenty of designs and even kits.